# bokeh turn on grid image

Tags: python, figure, bokeh

I just can't seem to grok plotting library documentation!
I have spent ages looking at the documentation for Bokeh and I can't figure out how to turn on the grid for this example: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/image.html
This is despite the fact that the thumbnail for this example actually does show the grid as seen here: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/

I have tried looking at other gallery examples which do have grids visible but alot of them make no mention of grid.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you have uncovered a deficiency in the current version (0.8.1) of Bokeh. The `Image` glyph was move to the `underlay` render level, which is the same as the grid. If you pan the plot, you will see the grid *is* actually on, the image is just on top of it. This might OK sometimes, but there is unfortunately not any way to change the render level back lower if that is what is desired. I've made an issue you can track:

https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/2040

This will be fixed in the 0.9 release.

Comment: Oh ok thanks! It's a really cool framework. I just thought it was me as I'm quite new to the likes of this and matplotlib etc.